# Which image is displayed on Mac desktop?

Tags: macos, desktop-customization

I have set up my Mac (10.6.4) to display random image from iPhoto on desktop.

From time to time I would like to know which image is displayed (I have a lot of them), but I could not find a way how to do it.

Something like `right click > show file` (like iPhoto has) would be great.

Answer (score 2):

The following Applescript should work:

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        tell current desktop
            set desktopProperties to (get item 3 of (get properties as list) as text)
        end tell
    end tell
    tell application "Finder"
    reveal desktopProperties
    end tell
end run
```

In Snow Leopard, to turn this into a useful action, open up `Automator.app` and from the template menu select `Service`.

In the top bar, make it read: Service receives `No input` in `any application`. Then drag `Run Applescript` from the Library pane beneath it and paste the above Applescript code into that window (replacing the default template code).

Save it as a suitably named workflow (e.g. `Show Wallpaper`). This will then appear as an action in the Services menu of all applications, or you can assign it a keyboard shortcut in the `System Preferences\Keyboard Shortcuts` pane under `Services`.

References:

1. http://ask.metafilter.com/89541/OSX-Leopard-How-to-show-the-current-wallpaper-in-finder

Comment: The code you have provided always opens default wallpaper `/Library/Desktop Pictures/Nature/Aurora.jpg`.

Comment: Noted. I've amended the above Applescript so that it should now work.

Comment: I am still getting Aurora.jpg every time.

Comment: Now it points to file in iPhoto Library, but to the wrong file.

Comment: Looks like it is a known problem. The article you link to says (in the comments) `there is no way to get the current random wallpaper`.